# Binary Decision Diagram of $(A\Rightarrow C)\wedge (B\Rightarrow C)$?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages

I made a Binary Decision Diagram for $(A\vee B)\Rightarrow C$, which i think is correct.

[image: Binary Decision Diagram]

---

Know i want o make a Binary Decision Diagram for $(A\Rightarrow C) \wedge (B\Rightarrow C)$ but i can't. I can make 2 BDD's, one for $(A\Rightarrow C)$ and one for $(B\Rightarrow C)$. In the picture bellow is just the BDD for $(A\Rightarrow C)$ because the other is the same just instead of $A$ it is $B$. How can i make one BDD for $(A\Rightarrow C) \wedge (B\Rightarrow C)$ ?

[image]

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A\Rightarrow C)\lor(B\Rightarrow C) \equiv (\lnot A\lor C)\lor(\lnot B\lor C)\equiv \lnot A\lor\lnot B\lor C$.

So, this is true iff either $A$ is false or $B$ is false, or $C$ is true.

Comment: I just realized there is a small mistake. It should be $(A\Rightarrow C)\wedge (B\Rightarrow C)$, could you correct it ?